# Why I cannot reproduce the volatile bug from Richter's CLR via C#

Tags: c#, volatile

I learn multithreading with Richter's famous book and coded a test to research and understand the volatile behaviour (CLR via C#, 4th edition, CHAPTER 29: Primitive Thread Synchronization Constructs, page 764). Richter says that processor could reverse the order of load from and store to RAM operations and this could cause some unpredictable behaviour. Also, I read a lot of articles on the web that confirmed the bug described by Richter. However, my test never reproduces this situation and always fails. My question is: what do I make wrong and why I cannot reproduce this bug?

Here is my processor model and building settings:
Core i7-7700HQ (4 cores, hyperthreading), 
Release x86, Optimize flag **on** (Richter asserts these settings could cause the bug), .NET 4.6.1, VS 2017, NUnit, test UI from ReSharper.

Here is the code

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class ReversedOrderBugTest
{
    [Test]
    public void ReversedOrderBug_Run_ReturnsTrue()
    {
        ReversedOrderBug rob = new ReversedOrderBug { AttemptsNumber = 1000000 };
        bool hasBug = rob.Run();
        Assert.True(hasBug);
    }
}

public class ReversedOrderBug
{
    private int _A;
    private int _B;

    // According to Richter, the processor could store _B before _A.
    // However, according to MSND, this statement is wrong because the CLR
    // prohibits reversing the order of sequential storing operations:
    private void Task1()
    {
        _A = 1;
        _B = 1;
    }

    // Here we try to reproduce the moment when _A = 0 and _B = 1,
    // and, also, the reversed order of reading operations  (the
    // case when _A is read before _B):
    private int Task2()
    {
        if (_B == 1) return _A;
        else retutn -1;
    }

    /// <summary>The number of attempts to reproduce the bug.</summary>
    public int AttemptsNumber { get; set; } = int.MaxValue;

    /// <summary>Reproduces the "_A = 0 and _B = 1" bug.</summary>
    /// <returns>True if the bug is caught, False otherwise.</returns>
    public bool Run()
    {
        // Loop the code from Richter's book until we get _A = 0 and _B = 1:
        for (int i = 0; i < AttemptsNumber; i++)
        {
            // Reset variables before each loop:
            _A = 0;
            _B = 0;

            // Run and wait for tasks:
            Task task1 = Task.Run(() => Task1());
            Task<int> task2 = Task.Run(() => Task2());
            Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);

            // Break the loop only when _A = 0 and _B = 1:
            if (task2.Result == 0) return true;
        }

        // The previous loop could not catch the moment when _A = 0 and _B = 1:
        return false;
    }
}
```

The revised version of ReverseOrderBug class that uses threads instead of Tasks and added a random delay to imitate asynchronicity:

1) The first method Run1 creates and runs the threads manually using new Thread() constructor. It works much slower than ThreadPool or Tasks' analogues. This is predictable because the method creates a lot of new threads and this hurts performance.

2) The second Run2 method uses ThreadPool and is much faster because it queues threads from the thread pool and creates new ones only if it is really necessary.

Also, I add a RandomDelay call inside Task1 and Task2 methods. However, the result is still the same: the test always fails.
I also should mention that manual reversion of variables reading in the Task2 method makes the test successful (first read _A, then _B). But, I am sure that the reverse reading is not the reason for this success. Conversely, it demonstrates that the CLR or processor does not reverse reading operations!

Here is the revised code:

```cs
public class ReversedOrderBug
{
    private int _A;
    private int _B;
    private readonly RandomNumberGenerator _Random = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();

    private void RandomDelay(bool longerDelay = true)
    {
        var data = new byte[2];
        _Random.GetNonZeroBytes(data);

        var number = longerDelay
            ? (data[0] + data[1]) * 100
            : data[0] * 10;

        while (number > 0) number--;
    }

    // According to Richter, the processor could store _B before _A.
    // However, according to MSND, this statement is wrong because the CLR
    // prohibits reversing the order of sequential storing operations:
    private void Task1Cst(CancellationTokenSource cst)
    {
        RandomDelay();
        _A = 1;
        _B = 1;
        cst.Cancel();
    }

    // Here we try to reproduce the moment when _A = 0 and _B = 1,
    // and, also, the reversed order of reading operations  (the
    // case when _A is read before _B):
    private int Task2Cst(CancellationTokenSource cst)
    {
        RandomDelay();
        var result = _B == 1
            ? _A
            : -1;

        cst.Cancel();
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>The number of attempts to reproduce the bug.</summary>
    public int AttemptsNumber { get; set; } = int.MaxValue;

    /// <summary>Reproduces the "_A = 0 and _B = 1" bug. Creates threads manually.</summary>
    /// <returns>True if the bug is caught, False otherwise.</returns>
    public bool Run1()
    {
        // Loop the code from Richter's book until we get _A = 0 and _B = 1:
        for (int i = 0; i < AttemptsNumber; i++)
        {
            // Reset variables before each loop:
            _A = 0;
            _B = 0;

            var result = 1;
            var cst1 = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var cst2 = new CancellationTokenSource();

            // Run and wait for tasks:
            var t1 = new Thread(() => Task1Cst(cst1));
            var t2 = new Thread(() => result = Task2Cst(cst2));

            t1.Start();
            t2.Start();

            while (!(cst1.Token.IsCancellationRequested && cst2.Token.IsCancellationRequested)) ;

            // Break the loop only when _A = 0 and _B = 1:
            if (result == 0) return true;
        }

        // The previous loop could not catch the moment when _A = 0 and _B = 1:
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>Uses ThreadPool to create threads.</summary>
    public bool Run2()
    {
        // Loop the code from Richter's book until we get _A = 0 and _B = 1:
        for (int i = 0; i < AttemptsNumber; i++)
        {
            // Reset variables before each loop:
            _A = 0;
            _B = 0;

            var result = 1;
            var cst1 = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var cst2 = new CancellationTokenSource();

            // Run and wait for tasks:
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => Task1Cst(cst1));
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => result = Task2Cst(cst2));
            while (!(cst1.Token.IsCancellationRequested && cst2.Token.IsCancellationRequested)) ;

            // Break the loop only when _A = 0 and _B = 1:
            if (result == 0) return true;
        }

        // The previous loop could not catch the moment when _A = 0 and _B = 1:
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did Richter use Task?  Seems doubtful, you'll never see it with this program.  It requires the two methods to run at (almost) the exact same time.  Can't happen here, starting a task takes much longer than the method takes, so Task1 will be long done before Task2 starts running.  Accidental synchronization is the core reason why you should never write code like this, only goes wrong once a month.

Comment: Thank you. You are right, Richter didn't use Tasks. I will try threads instead.

Comment: Hans, I followed your advice and coded 2 methods that create and run threads 1) manually or 2) with ThreadPool. However, the result is still the same: the test always fails (see the revised code above).

Comment: Add a `ManualResetEvent` into the mix, construct it unsignaled, wait for it in both methods, and set it before waiting for the tasks to finish. This still doesn't seem to make the code "fail" with the problem described. Next question then is how to *correctly* provoke this problem.

Comment: I run this test with int.MaxValue loops and it still failed. That's why I thought maybe Microsoft changed something in .NET 4.6?

Comment: I know about ManualResetEvent and implemented additional Run methods with this pattern. However, the result is the same. Also, I prefer CancelationToken above because it is more lightweight than ManualResetEvent and all the operations are extremely fast.

Comment: I sent an email to Jeffrey Richter (his email is publicly known since he works for Wintellect). Let's hope he can weigh in, and bothers with reading unknown peoples email.

Comment: Thank you! Let's hope together)))

Comment: On page 764, I talk about how to see the behavior of my StrangeBehavior class; not my ThreadsSharingData class. I haven't tried it with the latest CLR x86 JIT compiler but I suspect that StrangeBehavior should still work as a describe in my book.

As for my ThreadsSharingData code: The CLR specification states that re-ordering CAN happen. However, Microsoft's actual CLR implementation forces all writes to be in order and so, when using Microsoft's CLR, you will not be able to reproduce the bad behavior. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941249/understanding-clr-2-0-memory-model